# Restful asp.net api and using json in android application

Tags: c#, android, linq, rest, asp.net-web-api

I use [this tutorial](http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/) to create a restful asp.net web api for my android application, everything goes well and seems well, but my android application (based on tutorial part 2) can't communicate with db and always return 0 when I fetch some data.
I should mention that I use linq for connecting to db and in my api service I return a list of object (List)...
I need some way to test my api , is there anyway?! For example call api from browser or something like that to see the json array that return...
Also I have a question about the dll in the tutorial. Are they safe and okey?!

If anyone have better solution to have the functionality like the tutorial ones please suggest me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this google chrome plugin does what you want: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: thanks @Ryan Dansie, I add this plugin but my question is now this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699164/call-asp-net-json-api-with-simulating-android-httpurlconnection

Comment: You can use fiddler. It lets you make http requests and then see the response.